# express.js: capture generic routes with numeric Id

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, express, routes

I'm trying to define a generic handler for express.js routes

the idea is to get something like

get /api/xxx/yyy -> get all data

get /api/xxx/yyy/11-> get record 11

I need to capture xxx/yyy on one variable and 11 in another

this works fine:

```
app.get('/api/*', function(req, res, next) {
```

I'm not capturing anything, but I read it with the req.path property

But I can't seem to solve this:

```
app.get('/api/*/:id(\\d+)$', function(req, res, next) {
```

If I try with:

```
http://localhost:3000/api/clientes/2
```

this is what I get in req.params:

```
req.params = [ '2', id: 'clientes' ]
```

It seems like the path get binded to id, and the id is unbound to any variable.

moreover, if I try fetching this:

```
http://localhost:3000/api/clientes/nuevos/2
```

The route doesn't match

So, I'm looking for a regexp that allow me to catch several paths (xxx/yyy) and also the last one if it's a number (11)

Answer (score 0):

I could solve it using a regular expression instead of a string:

```
app.get(/\/api\/(.*)\/(\d+)/, function(req, res, next) {
```

Now if I try with

```
http://localhost:3000/api/clientes/menores/71
```

I get

```
req.params = [ 'clientes/menores', '71' ]
```

But I'd like to know if there's some way to use the :id marker...